# How to keep Broadcast Receiver after app is Killed and phone rebooted

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've successfully used a Broadcast Receiver for messages ,it works even if the app was killed ,it also works after reboot,**however if the app was killed and  the device rebooted** ,it doesn't work. Here is the XML

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:stopWithTask="false" 
android:exported="true" android:enabled="true" 
android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647"   >

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in your broadcast receivers `onRecive` method for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent and start your service. Something like this

```
if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: Yes I also did that ,but still problem persists ,actually no  permission shows at the start of the activity for receiving boot.

Comment: try to change the name of the receiver to its full package name. like `app.path.to.Receiver. SmsReceiver`. For whatever reason, it helps sometimes. I don't see anything wrong with what you've got so far

Comment: As I said the Broadcast works perfectly if there was a **kill** or a **reboot** but not both ,its as simple code ,try it yourself and if it works,send it to me.If it worked for me I will accept your answer